# How to persist failed action on app kill and dispatch them on app reopen?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

Offline status of actions is persisted properly. "persist/REHYDRATE" action has expected payload including the offline state. But after rehydrate, outbox turns 0.

Is there any way to handle this? or any another library that supports re-dispatch or reperforms of actions those were done in an offline mode that does even after app kill.

Link to git issue :
https://github.com/redux-offline/redux-offline/issues/151

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is no need to setup redux-persist. React-Offline does everything for you.
Elaborated in Redux-Offline Git issue

https://github.com/redux-offline/redux-offline/issues/151